# Explanation as to why this String comparison results in false?

Tags: kotlin

Could anyone explain why the following line of code results in false.

The code returns true if the Strings aren't capitalized. Shouldn't ignoring the case mean the result is the same?

```
System.out.print(
    String("Carthorse".toCharArray().sortedArray())
   .equals(String("Orchestra".toCharArray().sortedArray()),true)
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sorting does not ignore cases, here's what you're actually comparing:

```
//Caehorrst vs. Oacehrrst
```

Try the following instead:

```
val s1 = String("Carthorse".toLowerCase().toCharArray().sortedArray())
val s2 = String("Orchestra".toLowerCase().toCharArray().sortedArray())
println("$s1 vs. $s2, equal? ${s1==s2}")
//acehorrst vs. acehorrst, equal? true
```

Or with a bit more `fun`:

```
fun String.sortedCaseIgnore() = 
    String(toLowerCase().toCharArray().sortedArray())
val s1 = "Carthorse".sortedCaseIgnore()
val s2 = "Orchestra".sortedCaseIgnore()
```

And btw, use `println()` in favor of `System.out.println()`, here's its definition (part of Kotlin's standard library, no explicit import required):

```
public inline fun println(message: Any?) {
    System.out.println(message)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer